# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError-aparajita

Tags: java, eclipse

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Maven/mvnproj/test1 has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

This error I found,but could not debug as did not find any incompatibility.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Something has been compiled with Java 10, you can't use Java 8 to run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)